# Does it matter what encryption type I have installed locally if I am making a plugin for another wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

When I go to download wordpress there is 3 options a zip, a link that says md5 and one that says sha1. I know the wordpress and php version of the site I want to make the plugin for but I do not know, however, if not having the same encryption will cause a hiccup when installing/running the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Won't cause any issues as long as it is build to the Codex standard.